# Sort by one specific values Pyhon Visual Basic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

can someone help me with a job I'm doing,
I have a dataframe with a column (A) with str values ​​like:
'1 months', '2 months', '13 -16 months ',' + 24 months ', '20 -21 months' ...
and another column with numerical values ​​(B)
and I have to sort the rows using those two columns by or which I use:

1 df.sort_values(['A', 'B'])

my problem is that the months are ordered like this:
+24 months, 1 months, 13-, 2, 20-, 3, .....

Does anyone know how you could put it to be:
1, 2, 3, ...., 13-, 20-, +24

thank you very much

Comment: Can you please include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firstly extract the first integer by using [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) into a new column called `A_num` and use it for sorting, as follows:

```
(df.assign(A_num=df['A'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int))
   .sort_values(['A_num', 'B'])
   .drop(columns='A_num'))
```

### Test Run

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1 months', '2 months', '13 -16 months ',' + 24 months ', '20 -21 months'], 'B': [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]})

(df.assign(A_num=df['A'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int))
   .sort_values(['A_num', 'B'])
   .drop(columns='A_num'))


                A  B
0        1 months  4
1        2 months  3
2  13 -16 months   5
4   20 -21 months  1
3    + 24 months   2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive a column from the first column to get the month values, and then sort by that derived column and second column. Try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv", names=["A", "B"])
'''
                 A       B
0       1 months'   Test 1
1        2 months'  Test 2
2  13 -16 months '  Test 3
3      + 24 months  Test 4
4   20 -21 months'  Test 5
'''

df["C"] = df.apply(lambda row: int(re.sub(r"[^\d\s\-]","",row[0]).strip().split()[0]), axis=1)
'''
calculate the derived column from first column by getting the first month from string and convert it to int
                 A       B   C
0       1 months'   Test 1   1
1        2 months'  Test 2   2
2  13 -16 months '  Test 3  13
3      + 24 months  Test 4  24
4   20 -21 months'  Test 5  20
'''
df.sort_values(["C", "B"], inplace=True)
'''
sort the dataframe by Derived column 'c' and 'b'
                 A       B   C
0       1 months'   Test 1   1
1        2 months'  Test 2   2
2  13 -16 months '  Test 3  13
4   20 -21 months'  Test 5  20
3      + 24 months  Test 4  24
'''
df.drop("C", axis=1, inplace=True)
'''
finally drop the derived column 'c'
                 A       B
0       1 months'   Test 1
1        2 months'  Test 2
2  13 -16 months '  Test 3
4   20 -21 months'  Test 5
3      + 24 months  Test 4
'''
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, it's great, thanks a lot